# trying to set up several auth permission with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

```js
      .state('newProduct', {
        url: '/products/new',
        templateUrl: 'app/products/templates/product-new.html',
        controller: 'ProductNewCtrl',
        authenticate: 'cook,admin'
      })
```

I'm trying to add different client routes based on role authentifications but if I try to add another role such as cook for example it won't trigger the page defined by the url for both of them. It will work separately tho if that makes more sense
authenticate: 'cook',
authenticate: 'admin'

is this a syntax error?

Comment: "Won't work" is a little vague. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Are you using external module? What is `authenticate: 'cook,admin'`? Please describe what you're trying to achieve with this code so we can help. Also, if this question is related to `ui-router` then please tag it correctly with the [angular-ui-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-router) tag

Comment: yes it's using ui-router
I embedded the main component so you get the idea of what I'm trying to do https://embed.plnkr.co/vyNK5jNNuqgVC5BRP0ol/

Answer (score 0):

In your .state block, 'authenticate' is simply a data holder
You will need to do a manual check on the value of authenticate to handle permissions.

For example:

```
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
     $stateProvider
      .state("newProduct", {
        url: '/products/new',
        templateUrl: 'app/products/templates/product-new.html',
        controller: 'ProductNewCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      })
    });
```

Where you require to check permissions, you you will need access the $state u want using the $state object.
for example in your controller inject the $state object and use:

```
      if($state.get('newProduct').authenticate){ //if(true) in this case)
      //do what u want
      }
```

If you want to check permissions everytime u change state/screen heres an example for that too:

```
   angular.module("myApp").run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthService) {
   $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState,
   toParams,fromState, fromParams){
     if (toState.authenticate){
     // User is authenticated
     // do what u want
     }
    });
   });
```

Comment: I think that since the OP is asking about [2 roles] you should include an example of splitting the string the array and demonstrate how to check if a specific role exist in it

Comment: @ben Change `authenticate: 'cook,admin'` to `authenticate: ['cook', 'admin']` and in this answer, where it's written `if($state.get('newProduct').authenticate) {`, you can change it to `if($state.get('newProduct').authenticate.indexOf('cook') != -1) { alert( "user is a cook")` - This is the general idea with arrays - `.indexOf` will return `-1` if the elements doesn't exists in the array or the current position of the element in the array (which is zero-based)

Comment: two issues next.authenticate is for some reasons logging all the roles ['cook', 'admin'] so of course the comparison won't work and that's the issue I need to fix and second thing is should it be role[0] instead of role to get the value instead of the array ?

Answer (score 0):

found the fix thanks to Alon indexOf it got me thinking :)

```js
.run(function($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and the user is not logged in
    // also if the user role doesn't match with the one in `next.authenticate`
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {
      if (next.authenticate) {
        var loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn(function(role) {
          if (role && next.authenticate.indexOf(role[0]) !== -1) {
            console.log('works')
            return; // logged in and roles matches
          }

          event.preventDefault();
          if(role) {
            // logged in but not have the privileges (roles mismatch)
            console.log(next.authenticate.indexOf(role[0]));
            $state.go('onlyAdmin');
          } else {
            // not logged in
            $state.go('login');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```